# SQL Server 2016 - Auditing a view

Tags: sql-server-2016, audit

What is the best way to audit a view? I set up an audit which outputs to a file, set up a database audit specification for select, insert, delete, update for that view for a specific user (even though I think there should only be select). I enabled the audit and it created the file. However, 24 hours later, there is nothing in that file (other than the initialization info). Is this the right way to audit a view? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the configuration for the server audit and the database audit specification?

Comment: Something was misconfigured, I don't remember what, I didn't get an answer right away and I didn't check back.. sorry!

Answer (score 0):

If you have Sql-Server 2016 SP1 or newer you can audit anything.

Comment: make your answer more specific